# Databingding V2 and kotlin,I can not find my BR?

Tags: android, data-binding, kotlin

Yesterday, I updated my Android Studio to 3.1. So I can only use Databinding V2.I can build successfully in Java.But fail in Kotlin.It told me `Unresolved reference: BR`

### layout

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <data>
        <variable
            name="mainViewModel"
            type="com.example.shao.myapplication.ViewModel" />
    </data>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@{mainViewModel.title}"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

### in Java

```
public class MainActivity2 extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ActivityMainBinding binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main);
    binding.setVariable(BR.mainViewModel, new ViewModel());
}


public static int getMainBr() {
    return BR.mainViewModel;
}
```

}

### in kotlin

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    val mBinding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView<ActivityMainBinding>(this, R.layout.activity_main)
    mBinding.setVariable(BR.mainViewModel, ViewModel())
}
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**Android’s Data Binding with Kotlin**

First of all, after having a created Android project in Android Studio, we need to add the Data Binding dependency and the ones of Kotlin to the build.gradle file of our app.

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'                       
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
android {
....
dataBinding {
    enabled = true
}
}
dependencies {
...
// notice that the compiler version must be the same than our gradle version
kapt 'com.android.databinding:compiler:2.3.1'
}
```

**First we need to create a model. In this case a basic one like User.kt**

```
data class User(val name: String, val age: Int)
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
    <variable
        name="user"
        type="com.kuma.sample.User"
        />
</data>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.kuma.sample.MainActivity"
    >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/user_name_text_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="16dp"
        android:text="@{user.name}"
        tools:text="Name"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/user_age_text_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="16dp"
        android:text="@{Integer.toString(user.age)}"
        tools:text="XX"
        />

</LinearLayout>

 </layout>
```

**Kotlin Class**

```
package com.kuma.sample

 import android.databinding.DataBindingUtil
 import android.os.Bundle
 import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
 import com.kuma.kotlinsteps.databinding.ActivityMainBinding

 class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    val binding: ActivityMainBinding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main)

    val user = User("Kuma", 23)
    binding.setVariable(BR.user, user)
    binding.executePendingBindings()
}

}
```

**Solve Error Br**

```
enter code hereapply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
 android {
compileSdkVersion 24
buildToolsVersion "24.0.0"

defaultConfig {
applicationId "com.example.icarusud.recyclerviewtest"
minSdkVersion 15
targetSdkVersion 24
versionCode 1
versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
dataBinding {
    enabled true
}
sourceSets {
    main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
}
}
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.1.1'
compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"

//recyclerview
compile "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.1.1"

 //lastadapter
  compile 'com.github.nitrico.lastadapter:lastadapter:1.1.1'

kapt "com.android.databinding:compiler:2.1.2"
}
repositories {
mavenCentral()
}

kapt { generateStubs = true }
```

Change your gradle setting according to below code try this code it helps you.

Comment: I'm sorry, I used StackOverflow for the first time

Comment: Can you explain what exactly causes the issue and why your version works?

Answer (score 1):

change

```
mBinding.setVariable(BR.mainViewModel, ViewModel())
```

to

```
mBinding.mainViewModel=ViewModel()
```

Answer (score 0):

I worked around this issue by adding a `BRUtils.java`, then in the Kotlin files, accessing `BR` values in `BRUtils.java`

`BRUtils.java`:

```java
/**
 * since {@link BR} cannot be resolved in kotlin files during compile time
 * for some reason, created this file to hold getters for {@link BR} fields
 * that can then be accessed from said kotlin files.
 */
public class BRUtils {
    private BRUtils() {}

    public static int getMainViewModel() {
        return BR.mainViewModel;
    }
}
```

`something.kt`:

```
binding.setVariable(BRUtils.getMainViewModel(), ViewModel())
```